# AWX Ansible - Python requirement for endpoint nodes

Tags: ssh, python, redhat-enterprise-linux, ansible

I have setup my inventory in AWX and I am trying to do a simple ping command. I am getting the following error:

```
SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 
192.168.168.21 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Connection to 192.168.168.21 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory\r\n", 
    "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 127
}
```

Does this mean that any node that awx wants to run commands on will need python? Seems kind of strange to me. It is either that I am doing something wrong or it was built with the requirement of python for all nodes it is managing.. I would assume it would use python on (awx_task or awx_web), sub process to ssh and connect to the host and run shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go a level down (or up?). Ansible requires python to be installed in the machines that it connects to. And AWX is a UI/API around Ansible.

The only module I know that doesn't requires python is the [`raw`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/raw_module.html) module.

My suggestion would be to first get a bit more familiar with Ansible if you are going to use AWX or Ansible Tower.